# Is there is a way how avoid UNION ALL in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have multiple queries, which show the same variables. However, the only difference is in WHERE conditions. i.e.

```
SELECT (price*quantity) as total, date, CASE when type='Yes' then 'USA. YES' else 'USA. NO' end as name
from DB1
where name = 'manuf'
and export = 'yes'
union all

SELECT (price*quantity) as total, date, CASE when type='Yes' then 'BRAZIL. YES' else 'BRAZIL. NO' end as name
from DB1
where name = 'extra'
and export = 'yes'
and import = 'yes'
```

As a result, I want to save some time, because actually these queries take a lot of time to run and using UNION ALL runs every query multiple times. I was thinking about how can I do it less complex, so the query runs less time. Are there any opportunities to avoid UNION ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `case` expression and expand the `where`:

```
select (price*quantity) as total, date,
       (case when name = 'manuf' and type = 'Yes' then 'USA. YES'
             when name = 'manuf' then 'USA. NO'
             when name = 'extra' and type = 'Yes' then 'BRAZIL. YES' 
             then 'BRAZIL. NO'
        end) as name
from DB1
where (name = 'manuf' and export = 'yes') or
      (name = 'extra' and export = 'yes' and import = 'yes');
```